# How do I remotely fetch files from redirected URLs from a terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, download, wget, curl

I want to fetch a tarball of this python library from terminal.
https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/downloads

However, I cannot simply call

```
wget https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/tarball/master
```

because doing so retrieves a web page. How do I fetch this resource from terminal?

Comment: web browser from terminal, such as lynx?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `curl` instead – and if you know it's a tar archive, you can just pipe the output into `tar` to extract it automatically.

```
curl -L https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/tarball/master | tar xz
```

If you just want to save the file, use the `-o` option with your own name, or try `-O`, which will use the remote file name automatically (but might not always work).

From `man curl`:

> `-L`: If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new place